# How do you create CouchDB Views using Spring Bean Deployment with LightCouch

Tags: spring-mvc, couchdb

I am using Spring-MVC LightCouch and CouchDB and I have custom Views that need to be inserted into the DB on deployment. I have found the LightCouch has a method for pulling documents "from desk" as noted on their website:

```
DesignDocument designDoc = dbClient.design().getFromDesk("example");  
Response response = dbClient.design().synchronizeWithDb(designDoc);
```

This Works good from within JAVA code, however I need to be able to do it in the Spring ApplicationContext.xml I have more than one so I would like to mimick the call of:

```
dbClient.dessign().synchronizeAllWithDB()
```

How would I do this in the bean definition of the ApplicationContext I already have this:

```
<bean id="dbClient" class="org.lightcouch.CouchDbClient" lazy-init="false" destroy-    method="shutdown">
<constructor-arg value="couchdb.properties" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up having to make a bean that synchronized the database on init and created that when the app starts

Comment: <bean id="dbSync" class="org.lds.ctaft.clients.DBSync" lazy-init="false"> <constructor-arg ref="dbClient"/> </bean>

Comment: fyi, since 0.0.5 release, this feature is included under a client instance directly; an `init-method` of `dbClient` would now suffice.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you can't do it with Spring xml config, as the init method falls under a different instance; that is returned by the call to `design()` factory method.  Maybe you can try Java code equivalence, i.e. `@PostConstruct`.

Comment: Correct I am not able to do it using the spring xml I ended up having to make a bean that synchronized the database on init and created that when the app starts <bean id="dbSync" class="org.lds.ctaft.clients.DBSync" lazy-init="false">
        <constructor-arg ref="dbClient"/>
     </bean>